# Regex search and replace YouTube shortcode

Tags: regex, wordpress, youtube, embed, shortcode

I have a WordPress plugin where I recently used regex to search and replace, however, I am finding it tricky to remove a space that now remains.

I have a YouTube link, which I managed to use regex to add:

```
[embed](youtubelinkhere)[/embed]
```

However, there is a space that I can't get rid of before `[/embed]` that is causing some issues.

What should I search for to remove this space before `[/embed]` please?

Many thanks.

Comment: you can search `\s[\/embed]` and replace with `[/embed]`

Comment: Thanks for your response...

Unfortunately, the plugin gave me this error:
Invalid regular expression: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to escape the square brackets:

```
\s\[\/embed\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/fT4dP3/1

Comment: Perfect thank you, just had to add "\s\[\/embed\]" so the plugin could understand it correctly.